# how to connect dual monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have AMD athlon(tm) II X2 270 processor ,2gb ram, AMD 760G onboard graphic adapter with one vga port..
Question 1. So does my pc support dual monitors?
If yes then 2nd problem is that...its only have one vga port 
And I have one screen with vga connection and other with hdmi.....
Question 2. how I connect both screen to my pc one have vga ,other have hdmi ..but pc has single vga port?

Help ...thanku

Comment: It does not support it unless you are only looking to mirror the display.

Answer (score 1):

You can't on that graphics adaptor - you need to get an addon video card/GPU with 2 outputs (since chances are a system of that era would use the same PCIe lanes for both onboard or addon video) with a suitable interface - I'd assume PCIe but you need to check. Make sure it has the right interfaces - either a DVI-I or VGA for VGA and of course HDMI for HDMI too.

So... your PC doesn't support dual monitors, or your HDMI monitor as configured.